# Django Raw Field through multiple levels of relationship

Tags: django, django-models, foreign-keys, many-to-many

I have a Django project where we are linking multiple levels of relationships through FK's and Many to Many relationships.  Specifically I am trying to get the RAW ID field for one of these relationships but run into "has no attribute" or "unknown field specified"

I am attempting to get the note text field from the note model.

Thanks in advance:

```
class Organization(AbstractExclusions, AbstractManyToManyCommonInfo, AbstractCommonInfo, AbstractOrganizationLocationCommonInfo, AbstractAcvitivyInfo):
    note = models.ManyToManyField('Notes', through="OrganizationNote", blank=True)

class Notes(Model):
    note = models.TextField(blank=True)  #this is the field we are after from the Organization level

class OrganizationNote(Model):
    org = models.ForeignKey(Organization, on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True, null=True)
    note = models.ForeignKey(Notes, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('Organization Note')
        db_table = 'organization_notes'
```

For use in the following:

```
orgNoteFormSet = inlineformset_factory(custModels.Organization, custModels.Organization.note.through, form=OrganizationForm, extra=1,
    fields=('Notes.note field here',))
```

I have attempted the workaround to use a widget to format the field as I need, but when attempting to save the field, I get the following error: "Select a valid choice. That choice is not one"

Similar approach:

```
orgNoteFormSet = inlineformset_factory(custModels.Organization, custModels.OrganizationNote, form=OrganizationForm, extra=0, fields=[custModels.Notes._meta.get_field('note')], widgets={'note': forms.Textarea(attrs={'cols': 20, 'rows': 10})})
```

gives the following Error: TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, TextField found

Comment: What about `myorg.note.values_list('note', flat=True)`?

Comment: 'ManyToManyDescriptor' object has no attribute 'values_list' Is what I get there. More context added to question.

Comment: but this is if you have an `Organization` *object* `myorg`.